# Profiling the function 'library' in R

Tags: r, profiling

I'm trying to track down the reason(s) why a package I've put together loads slowly (relative to others, it's noticeably slower), and running this (using [`ggplot2`](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/ggplot2/index.html) as an example) doesn't appear to give any insight:

```
Rprof(line.profiling=TRUE)
library(ggplot2)
Rprof(NULL)
summaryRprof("Rprof.out", lines = "show")
```

which yields:

```
$by.self
              self.time self.pct total.time total.pct
<no location>       0.5      100        0.5       100
$by.total
              total.time total.pct self.time self.pct
<no location>        0.5       100       0.5      100
$by.line
              self.time self.pct total.time total.pct
<no location>       0.5      100        0.5       100

$sample.interval
[1] 0.02

$sampling.time
[1] 0.5
```

(And `Rprof.out` contains a mess of information I'm having trouble understanding.)

Can anyone suggest how I might "profile" what the function `library` is doing?  Or, am I taking the wrong approach?

Comment: To be clear, I'm definitely not suggesting `ggplot2` loads slowly.

Comment: I might be able to provide some guesses if you pointed to the source code of your package. I'd look at what you're doing in NAMESPACE, how many objects in your package environment, etc.

Comment: Thanks @hadley.  I'm sure you have better things to do, but the code base is here: https://github.com/abarbour/strain

Comment: I'd wonder about the number of Imports: would be interesting to profile that vs. Depends. If it made a big impact you could replace with specific importFrom calls.

Comment: It turns out importing `Matrix` was consuming most of the load time: `sapply(c("Matrix","lubridate","corpcor","zoo"), function(x) system.time(do.call("library",list(x))))`

Answer (score 3):

As it says in the *Line profiling* section of `?summaryRprof`:

> If the code being run has source reference information retained (via
>   `keep.source = TRUE` in `source` or `KeepSource = TRUE` in a package
>   `DESCRIPTION` file or some other way), then information about the
>   origin of lines is recorded during profiling.

By default, source code is not kept when building/installing packages.  You'll see non-trivial timings if you just run `summaryRprof()`.  You could always re-install the base package with `KeepSource=TRUE`, but that might be more trouble than it's worth.

Another alternative would be to use `debugonce(library)` to step through the `library` call line-by-line.  This is a bit brute-force, but it might be more obvious than combing through the profiling output.

Comment: Interesting points.  To clarify, when you write "the base package" do you mean the package I'm trying to study, or the package `base` so that the source code for `library` is retained?

Comment: @AndyBarbour: the latter.